# Is there any tutorial on creating a slideshow with transition and with images of different sizes all done from python script?

Tags: python, scripting, image

I would like to create a python script for blender that takes in paramater a set of different images of different size and create a slideshow with transition. When the image doesn't fit the camera view size i would like that the image would move with a ken burns effect. I would like to know for example how to fit the camera bounds to the size of a an image if possible and if not to fit the camera bounds to a portion of an image. All scene setup and rendering has to be done with a python script.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if it helps but take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcjJLhdeBz4

Comment: Thanks a part of the idea is there, i will try to replace text with images and see what is the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a concept tutorial that i made there is this addon from hapit at blenderartists forums http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?360518-Addon-Dynamic-Slideshow basically you use the inport images as planes then place an animated camera over each image. This animation is editable per camera and occurs simultaneously in the scene.  Then in the vse each camera gets its own strip to mix as tou like. This allows you to rearrange the order of playback easily.

The main point here is retaining the full image resolution which the vse cannot do as it always conforms source to project dimensions or crops at 1:1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i think this is what i needed to get started.